# from a service, turning one function into two different functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside a service which has lots of lines and I want to convert that function into two different functions

this is the function

```
angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleMobile.services')
  .factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory, LocalForageFactory, LeaguesFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {
    return {
      getSports: function(customer) {
        var defer = $q.defer(),
        _this = this;
    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
      .then(function(sports) {
        if (!_.isNull(sports)) {
          defer.resolve(sports);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + customer.agent)
            .success(function(sports) {
              sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                return sport.priority;
              });

              //THIS THE PART THAT I WANT TO MOVE FROM HERE

              _this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
                var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                    intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
                if (sports.length) {
                  sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
                    sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
                    return sport;
                  });
                }else {
                  AuthFactory.logout();
                }
              });
              LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
              defer.resolve(sports);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            });
        }
      });
    return defer.promise;
  }
});
```

and here is what I have so far but I am receiving an error **sports is not defined**

```
  getSports: function(customer) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
    _this = this;

    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
      .then(function(sports) {
        if (!_.isNull(sports)) {
          defer.resolve(sports);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + customer.agent)
            .success(function(sports) {
              sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                return sport.priority;
              });
              // HERE I AM CALLING THE NEW FUNCTION
              _this.intersectedSportsChecked(customer);

              LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
              defer.resolve(sports);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            });
        }
      });
    return defer.promise;
  },

  // HERE IS THE NEW FUNCTION
  // UPDATED

  intersectedSportsChecked: function(customer) {
    var _this = this,
        defer = $q.defer(),
        rejection = function(err) {
          defer.reject(err);
        };

    _this.getSports(customer).then(function(sports) {
      _this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
        var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
            intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
        if (sports.length) {
          sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
            sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
            return sport;
          });
        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }
      });
    }, rejection);
  },
```

so, what am I missing here ?

Comment: `sports` doesn't exist within `intersectedSportsChecked`. It is out of scope

Comment: and how do I declare it ? I did ```var sports = sports; ``` and still getting same error @elclanrs

Comment: That's the same, `sports` isn't defined. You'd have to call `getSports` and chain another promise and access `sports` within the callback.

Comment: @elclanrs can you just help with a little piece of code ?

Comment: Also, any chance that the retrieve from your `LocalForageFactory` returns `undefined` ? You are resolving sports if it is not `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work tbh, try passing an argument `sports` to `intersectedSportsChecked` so you call it like `_this.intersectedSportsChecked(sports, customer)`. But if you want to refactor that piece of code into a function, why does it have to be exported? Can't the function be declared within the scope of `getSports`?

Comment: @elclanrs if I pass ```sports``` as an arg, I get ```Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``` in the console

Comment: @MichaelP. there says ```if(!_.isNull(...))``` so it is not how you say I guess

Comment: `_.isNull(undefined)` returns `false`. You better check that `sports` is defined and not null.

Comment: Because you are braking the asynchronous flow. `intersectedSportsChecked` is async, therfore you have to use a callback, you can't expect that calling the function will update `sports` for the next line.

Comment: @elclanrs can you show me how to do it calling ```getSports``` with a promise in ```intersectedSportsChecked``` ?

Comment: There seems to be other issues, since I can try it I'm not sure I can help, plus angular and underscore specific code make it a bit hard to follow. But this line `LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);` doesn't look right because `sports` is probably not what you expect. The line `sports = sports.map(...)` happens inside an async callback, so that next line is troublesome.

Comment: @elclanrs see the update I did in the function with the promise calling ```getSports```. Everything is running fine if I don't split the function, the trouble comes once I try to to split the function, now is not giving me any errors, but is not returning the sports array I am expecting

Comment: @MichaelP. I did an update in my code in the second part of the question, now I am not getting errors but still not getting the array sports as I want. the trouble comes once I split the function, if I don't split it, works great.